# How to send message in gmail using data from MySQL (Formatted Message)

Tags: php, mysql, email, gmail

I have a php file that Inserts the ff. data to MySQL

- Email
- Message

After I insert that there is a 3rd party app that sends those message to the gmail of the receiver.

I wonder how can I configure my php file to insert the data formatted (bold,indent,...) in mysql and when that app sends it to gmail its properly formatted.

My codes for that is the parameters of email and message then Insert into.

I try this one

`$message = "<html>Test</html>";`

then do the `insert into` but it didnt work. When I view the message the `<html>` tag included

and also the third party application does send the message only using another gmail account. no additional additives

[image]

I tried anchor tag but it doesnt work

2nd try

[image]

Comment: How does the 3rd part retrieve that information?

Comment: Actually sir Im almost done no html included instead of <br> i used \n for new lines now the only problem im solving is how can I add a hyperlink?

Comment: An anchor tag should work.

Comment: what is the tag for that? you mean `<a href>` it displays as normal text

Comment: Even when received as an email? Some mailers have an option to set the content to HTML.

Comment: Sir please see my edited post

Comment: That's wrong and you have extra `>` it should be: `<a href="www.google.com"><span>link</span></a>`

Comment: copy and paste it sir and still the same

Comment: reedit my question and paste the image of the email

Comment: Were you able to make bold tags work? if yes show us how you did it

Comment: for now I only 2 tags equivalent of newline and hyperlink. I try to use `\n` and it work. is there any equivalent of that in hyperlink? bacause i only pass it as string only

Comment: You'll have to ask your 3rd party software on this or tell/show us the 3rd party app

Comment: actually sir the 3rd party part is to fetch the data from mysql then use a gmail account also to send those message to the receiver

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to update how it sends the mail using Gmail. The 3rd party is just sending that using code. It's usually there where you parse the HTML data

Comment: how can I achieve that sir? should i put html tags in my string?\

Answer (score 1):

When I need to store formatted text, I use HTML tags.  I don't know what your 3rd party is, but if they can handle HTML formatting, it could be a potential solution.

Comment: You mean I will encapsulate my string in HTML tags the insert that in my database also. Let me try sir I hope it work

Comment: Ah, that's different, then.  Some 3rd party senders will do HTML formatting, but apparently yours does not.

Comment: Actually sir Im almost done no html included instead of `<br>` i used `\n` for new lines now the only problem im solving is how can I add a hyperlink?

Comment: any hint sir? or guess

Comment: If the third party doesn't allow HTML then I'm not sure you can.  However you might want to contact them directly to find out

Comment: we try to talk to the 3rd party and the app does save and send it only. no more added.

Comment: is there some sort of tag? like on `stackoverflow`? the `[A]`